# Push but not compile on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

Is it possible to just commit things "quickly" to heroku without to have the whole thing parsed/compiled/reinstalled ? Sometimes i feel like it is not needed (for html or css for example)

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is yes, provided you are prepared to write your own custom buildpack. It also depends on your technology. Most Heroku buildpacks compile code from source as part of the application deployment. It is possible to create a custom buildpack that takes a pre-compiled binary instead, only updating the application's data or configuration.

For more information see:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
- http://www.petekeen.net/introduction-to-heroku-buildpacks